# where structured data is concerned, the flat file is as simple as it gets

Tags: comprehension

Example:

> **Where structured data is concerned**, the flat file is as simple as it gets. No, a flat file isn’t a folder that’s been squashed under a stack of books. Flat files are so called because they have minimal structure.

I'm not sure how I should understand the part in bold. Things that are of great importance when it comes to working with structured data are not at all important when dealing with flat files?

Comment: Nothing as fancy as that. It only means "in regard to structured data..." or "speaking of structured data...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you arrived at that interpretation.

Look at [definition #2 of 'concerned'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concerned) at Wiktionary:

> Involved or responsible. *Example: The people concerned have been punished.*

---

The usage you're asking about is close to 'involved'. It could be rephrased:

> Where structured data is involved, the flat file is as simple as it gets.

or

> When talking about structured data, the flat file is as simple as it gets.

or

> When considering structured data, the flat file is as simple as it gets.

or, more radically

> The flat file is the simplest type of structured data.